# Error react native running base starter app from bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

Walking through the react-native tutorial, (install prerequisites, then 'react-native init AwesomeProject', and 'react-native run-ios', runs fine in the simulator) when I open the xcode project and try to run from a local bundle (option 2 in AppDelegate.m) I get the following error:

`/Users/webb/projects/nativeapp/fuel/node_modules/node-haste/lib/index.js:331
Object.assign(DependencyGraph, {
       ^
TypeError: Object.assign is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/webb/projects/nativeapp/fuel/node_modules/node-haste/lib/index.js:331:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/webb/projects/nativeapp/fuel/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:166:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:16:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1`

The error persists if I run in release or debug build configuration.  And happens both on the simulator and device.  Pretty much I am only able to run the sample app with AppDelegate.m configured for option 1 (load from dev server) which wont fly when I want to publish my app.

I tried both node 5.8 and 6.1.  Can anyone else think of next steps in debugging?  This is just the base sample app, it should run from a local bundle right?

`"dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-native": "^0.25.1"
  }`

I am on a mac, have not tried android, but iOS is for sure non functional.

Comment: React Native 0.26 was released yesterday, it has the same exact problem.  Is no one running these example apps from a bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I started fresh on a new machine, everything works fine on a new machine.  So there was obviously something wrong on my old machine, I found mention that global CLI installs of Babel will cause funky issues like I was seeing.  This may have been the case, although it was still persisting after I uninstalled Babel.

My advice if you start to run into this is to not waste a week trying to solve it.  Reload your OS and start fresh.